# how to setup the configuration with "The requested service could not be activated" on a web server?

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am (trying) to host a WCF service in IIS on a "server" machine and access it from a separate "client" machine. All worked well in the development environment, but faults out when moved to the production machine.

The client receives the error:
    System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service,

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:43175/NovaWebSite/Nova.svc

could not be activated. See the
server's diagnositc trace logs for more information.

Having managed to configure tracing on my web server, the error log shows:

```
Description: Failed to open System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost 
Level:   Warning
Process Name: w3wp
Trace Identifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectOpenFailed.aspx
Activity Name: Open ServiceHost 'Nova.ClientProxy.NovaDataService
Source: System.ServiceModel
```

I know the problem is with the server, but I can not seem to figure this out. Any help would be *really* *really* appreciated!  (I'm sure there is a lot of stuff in here that is not needed, but I'm a complete newbie here.). Thanks!

Here are the configuration files:

project c:\nova5\WebSite\  has Nova.svc:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Nova.ClientProxy.NovaDataService"  %>
```

and a Web.config of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

 <system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>
 <services>
  <service name="Nova.ClientProxy.NovaDataService">
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid 
           disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

 <diagnostics>
  <messageLogging
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
      logMalformedMessages="true"
      logEntireMessage="true"
      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000"
      maxMessagesToLog="500" />
  </diagnostics>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true" >
      <listeners>
        <add name="xml"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <add name="xml"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="myUserTraceSource"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
      <listeners>
        <add name="xml"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="xml"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="Error.svclog" />
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

In the project Nova.ClientProxy, the App.config file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
 <services>
   <service name="Nova5.UI.DataServiceLibrary.NovaDataService">
     <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"   contract="Nova5.UI.DataServiceLibrary.INovaDataService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Nova5.UI.DataServiceLibrary/Service1/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to False before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>

 <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: Check the server's event viewer - when I run into this issue it's almost always something to do with the service throwing an error.